# Switch to Root User in a Dockerfile

Tags: sql-server, docker, ubuntu, root

I ran this command:

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

I then made a dockerfile to use this container image as a base image for another container

```
# escape=`
FROM  mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

COPY ./CompanyCert.crt  /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/CompanyCert.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates
```

When I try to build that docker file, I get this error:

> ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/ssl/certs/CompanyCert.pem': Permission denied

So I added a `RUN whoami` to my docker file and it returns *mssql*.  When I run `id -u` it returns 10001.  So it seems that the user *mssql* does not have root permissions.

I tried putting sudo in front of my call to `update-ca-certificates` but it says:

> /bin/bash: sudo: command not found

I tried to `RUN su -` and that returns:

> su: must be run from a terminal

I have successfully used the above dockerfile to install my company certificates on other containers from Microsoft, but it is failing spectacularly this time.

**How can I get root access so I can install my company certificate on this SQL Server Container?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `USER root` to your `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM  mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
USER root
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

COPY ./CompanyCert.crt  /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/CompanyCert.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thank you!